# I want to scan down column 1 and if, for each cell, it matches any of the cells in column 2 I want it to return the entry in column 2 it matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to scan down column A in sheet alpha (alpha!A) which is a list of emails such that if, for each cell A1,A2,...AX, the said cell matches *any* of the entries in column D of sheet beta (beta!D), then it returns the horizontally corresponding entry in beta!E. This last part of the output coming from beta!E is of lesser importance, simply the position# of the match in beta!D would suffice. 
Edit: Also it must also return an empty cell if there is no match between alpha!A and beta!D. 
Thanks much.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: it is helpful to use proper nomenclature `A.a` and easily be confused for, say `A:A` use `alpha!A1` if using formulas or `Worksheets("alpha").Range("A1")` if using VBA. That said, it looks like a [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) should do what you want.

Comment: I have tried vlookup, but I don't quite understand the column index input. I have also tried to make a logical expression, however I'm not sure it takes arrays, nor am I familiar with how to write compositional functions. Also the match function, but I'm not sure how I would make the match function scale down (drag down). It should also be mentioned that the inputs in A.a are from an importrange function.

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,BETA!D:E,2,FALSE)
```

The Column Index Number is asking you "how many columns to the right is the data you want?"  If your matching data is in column D, then D is 1, E is 2, etc.  So the formula can be interpreted as:

VLOOKUP(What are you looking for?, Where are you looking for it?, How far to the right is it located?, Do you want to use exact matches or approximate matches?)

Edit:  This will return "#N/A" if the term you are searching for does not exist in your beta!D:E range.  If you specifically need a blank cell returned in this case, then the simplest thing that I have found is just =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(yadda),"").  You can modify this to return anything you like in the cases where VLOOKUP fails.